# Decomposition of the Galois group

Tags: galois-theory

Let's take $p$ a prime number dans $n=n_1...n_r$ a natural number with his prime decomposition.
I would like to show if it's possible that
$Gal(F_{p^n}/F_p) ≅ Gal(F_{p^{n_1}}/F_p)\times...\times Gal(F_{p^{n_r}}/F_p)$.

My first first idea was to take the morphism $ Gal(F_{p^n}/F_p) \rightarrow Gal(F_{p^{n_1}}/F_p)\times...\times Gal(F_{p^{n_r}}/F_p) $ that send $\sigma \rightarrow ( \sigma_{|F_{p^{n_1}}}, ..., \sigma_{|F_{p^{n_r}}})$. So it is easy to show that it's a morphism.
The injectivity I don't know how. And the surjectivity is something with the cardinal maybe ?

If someone could help would be nice. Thank you !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is just Chinese Remainder Theorem, since ${\rm Gal}(\mathbb{F}_{p^m}/\mathbb{F}_p)\simeq \mathbb{Z}/m\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: But how do you show that ?

Comment: This is known. Precisely: 
the isomorphism above sends the class of $1$ to $\sigma: x\mapsto x^p$. Unfortunately,  I don't have the time to give more details  now.

 By the way, in order to give you helpful answers, It would be nice if you could tell us what you know and what you don't know about finite fields, because this result is one classical result of the theory.

Comment: Yes I am sorry that I didn't gave that details. But anyway thank you ! I will try to demonstrate this myself !

Comment: I'll try to post a proof later if you have some difficulties.